# iOS : How to check if date-time selected is valid time during day light savings?

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone, dst

I have a special case to check where a user inputs the future date and time and I need to verify if that time is valid (what do I mean by valid is explained below) considering user might be affected by daylight saving in his timezone.

**For Example:**

1. Assume the user's timezone is Adelaide, Australia. Open the [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/australia/adelaide) to see how timezone affects in Adelaide OR see below.

```
4 Oct 2020 - Daylight Saving Time Starts
When local standard time is about to reach
Sunday, 4 October 2020, 2:00:00 am clocks are turned forward 1 hour to 
Sunday, 4 October 2020, 3:00:00 am local daylight time instead.
```

2. Now based on the above information my understanding is if my user selected the date-time  between

> 4 October 2020, **2:01:00 am** - 4 October 2020, **2:59:00 am**

it's not valid as the hour is forwarded to 3 am.

How can I validate that in an iOS app? (Assuming i)

Basically I need to inform the user that the time selected is affected by DST and users need to select a different time.

I've looked into Date and Timezone APIs and couldn't seem to find anything which can validate this.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the user enter the date? I assume you do not use the UIDatePicker component, because this respects "non-exising" calendar dates and just does not allow the user the enter one.

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen UIDatePicker does allow you to select the time which does not exist but when you try to get the date object from date picker it changes the selected time to valid time. For example : If you select 2:30 am in example of the question than the date picker will give you 3:00 am.

Comment: That's strange - on my device, if I try to select a non-existing time, the picker will immediatly switch back to a different hour, e.g. won't let me select anything that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way would be to convert the string (or whatever the user enters, seems you are not using the `UIDatePicker`) into a date and check if this is possible.

For Mid-Europe, DST is starting on March 29th, 2020, so

```
let df = DateFormatter() 
df.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"Europe/Berlin")
df.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
if let theDate = df.date(from: "2020-03-29 02:01")
{
    print(theDate)
} else {
  print ("Illegal date")
}
```

will print *Illegal date*.
A little more tricky is switch back to non-DST, because (in Mid-Europe) there are two possible dates for `2020-10-25 02:01` - it could mean winter *or* summer time with two different UTC representations.